# Makefile, some sources in subdirectory

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a directory designed like this:

> makefile
>
> main.cpp
>
> > header.h
> >
> > src1.c
> >
> > src2.c

Here is (most of) my makefile:

```
SRC = subdir

# Main Dependencies
main.o: main.c $(SRC)/header.h

# Source Dependencies
$(SRC)/src1.o: $(SRC)/src1.c $(SRC)/header.h
$(SRC)/src2.o: $(SRC)/src2.c $(SRC)/header.h

#  Create archive from sources
$(SRC)/archive.a: $(SRC)/src1.o $(SRC)/src2.o
    ar -rcs $@ $^

# Compile rules
.c.o:
    gcc -c $(CFLG) $<
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $(CFLG) $<

#  Link main with archive
main: main.o $(SRC)/archive.a
    gcc -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)
```

When I run this, the .o files are all created within the root rather than subdir. It then crashes when making archive.a because the .o files are not in the expected location: "ar: subdir/src1.o: No such file or directory"

I tried removing $(SRC)/ from the .o files since that's not where they're actually created, but then it crashes when trying to compile src1.c.

What do I need to do to make this work? I'm sure I've made some silly mistake, but I'm not very familiar with makefiles. :/

I'd like the .o files to appear in a subdirectory, but if they show up in root that's also fine, as long as it compiles.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, with gcc 4.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler where to put the output files.  If you don't specify, then they're put into the current directory.

So change your rules to add the `-o` flag:

```
.c.o:
        gcc -c -o $@ $(CFLG) $<
.cpp.o:
        g++ -c -o $@ $(CFLG) $<
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. So, does -o $@ means use the target name for output?

Comment: Yes.  Make's automatic variable `$@` expands to the target name, and the compiler's `-o` flag specifies what to name the output file.